# What can cause JUnit to disregard @Ignore annotations?

Tags: java, junit

I just used MyEclipse to automatically generate some JUnit test cases. One of the generated methods looks like this:

```
@Ignore("Ignored") @Test
public void testCreateRevision()
{
    fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
}
```

I added the `@Ignore` annotation manually. However, when I run the test, JUnit lists that method, and others like it, under "failures," rather than ignoring them (related: [What's the difference between failure and error in JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425995/whats-the-difference-between-failure-and-error-in-junit)). And it displays the "Not yet implemented" message instead of the "Ignored" message. Clearly, `fail()` must be getting called, and therefore, the `@Ignore` assertion is not working.

What's going on here? Is there a setting I need to enable for this to work?

**EDIT :**
Things I have considered/tried so far:

- I am using JUnit 4, so it's not a version problem.
- I am importing `org.junit.Ignore`, so it's not a case of the wrong `Ignore` being used.
- I have tried using `@Ignore` alone, `@Ignore @Test` and `@Ignore("message") @Test`; all fail.

**EDIT 2 :**
I created the tests with MyEclipse, via `New > Other; Java > JUnit > JUnit Test Case; New JUnit 4 test`, and the library in my build path is JUnit 4. I'm building with ant and actually running the case with MyEclipse.

Comment: wild guess: Look at your import statements and make sure the annotation is `org.junit.Ignore` or whatever it's supposed to be, and not some other annotation from a totally different package which just happens to have the same name.

Comment: @Matrix, good thought, but I do have the right import.

Comment: Do you run JUnit 3 or Junit 4? JUnit 3 will ignore the annotation. To find out, rename the method to do not start with `test` and remove the @Ignore annotation and try again. If the test is not executed means that you are running Junit 3

Comment: As I stated in the initial and edited versions of the post, I am using JUnit 4.

Comment: How are you running the tests - in the IDE, from Maven, Ant, etc? How did you verify that the tests are run with a JUnit 4 runner?

Comment: @matt, I moved this comment (my reply to you) to the body of the question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Make sure you are importing the right `@Ignore`. To be sure use `@org.junit.Ignore` explicitly.
2. Double check if your test is being executed by JUnit 4, not 3. The easiest way to do this is to either change the test name so it is not prefixed by `test` (now it shouldn't be executed at all and JUnit 4 does not need this prefix anyway) or examine your test case inheritance hierarchy: it **shouldn't** extend directly or indirectly from `junit.framework.TestCase` (Junit 3 requirement).

Comment: I am, and it is; I updated my post while you were writing this answer. Thanks, though!

Comment: Argh, this turned out to be right! Someone else modified a superclass to be JUnit 3 while I was working and I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 16):

In JUnit5 use `@Disabled` or `@Disabled("Reason text")`

Comment: there's a typo, instead of "disable", it is "@Disabled"

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem also even though JUnit 3 was not on my classpath. I believe that compatibility mode on Junit 4 picks up on the 'test' prefix in your testname and thus operates as JUnit 3 would rather than picking up the @Ignore. The solution is to rename your test.

Comment: Superb, this helped. It was getting frustrating because the maven builds were ignoring the @ignore and then failed. Thank you!

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that new version of surefire plugin (version >=2.8) works with testXyz that's annotated with @Ignore, so you don't need to rename methods.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the test classes were recompiled?

It's a quite common problem, that the recompilation fails because there was typo somewhere in the sources (like a missing semicolon), and the IDE does not tell you that compiling failed.

Try deleting the `target/test-classes` folder.

Comment: or just using Project > Clean

Comment: @MatrixFrog: I kind of dislike `mvn clean`: deleting `target` is always faster than invoking clean. Also if you have a project with many classes and generated code, clean deletes more than appropriate.

Comment: Took me a while to find them (it's someone else's build script and I'm not familiar with it yet) but this doesn't seem to be my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found my IDE was executing the test disregarding the `@Ignore` annotation. When I ran `mvn install` (or any other maven phase) the test was skipped and that's what I was actually aiming for (see attached ilustration).

[Ilustration of ways of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqp1o.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring the test class is also imported fixed the issue for me i.e.

```
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its just @Ignore that will skip the test

[JUnit Ignore](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html)

Comment: I did try that, but you realize the page you linked to has both, right? "For example: `@Ignore @Test public void something() { ...`"