# JUnit ExpectedException rule doesn't work

Tags: java, junit

I have a method which I should test:

```
public void createNode(String name, String primaryNodeType, String[] mixinNodeTypes) throws RepositoryException {
    final Node parentNode = this.parentNodeStack.peek();
    boolean isParentImport = (name == null && isParentNodeImport);
    if (name == null) {
        if (this.parentNodeStack.size() > 1) {
            throw new RepositoryException("Node needs to have a name.");
        }
        name = this.defaultName;
    }
    //other stuff
}
```

In my test I put into method parameters with which method should throw a RepositoryException(Line 6).

```
@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class DefaultContentCreatorTest {

    static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "default-name";
    final Mockery mockery = new JUnit4Mockery();
    DefaultContentCreator contentCreator;

    Session session;
    Node parentNode;
    Property prop;

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        final SlingRepository repo = RepositoryProvider.instance().getRepository();
        session = repo.loginAdministrative(null);
        contentCreator = new DefaultContentCreator(null);
        contentCreator.init(U.createImportOptions(true, true, true, false, false),
                new HashMap<String, ContentReader>(), null, null);
        parentNode = session.getRootNode().addNode(getClass().getSimpleName()).addNode(uniqueId());
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() throws RepositoryException {
        if(session != null) {
            session.save();
            session.logout();
            session = null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void createNodeWithoutNameAndTwoInStack() throws RepositoryException {
        contentCreator.init(U.createImportOptions(true, true, true, false, false),
                new HashMap<String, ContentReader>(), null, null);
        //Making parentNodeStack.size() == 1
        contentCreator.prepareParsing(parentNode, DEFAULT_NAME);
        //Making parentNodeStack.size() == 2
        contentCreator.createNode(uniqueId(), null, null);

        //contentCreator.createNode method should now throw an exception
        thrown.expect(RepositoryException.class); //Doesn't work
        thrown.expectMessage("Node needs to have a name."); //Doesn't work
        contentCreator.createNode(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

However test fails with exactly this RepositoryException. What I'm doing wrong? BTW if I use `@Test(expected = RepositoryException.class)` everything works fine.

UPD: I'm writing unit test for one of Apache Sling classes. You can take a look on this class [here](https://github.com/PetrShypila/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/jcr/contentloader/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/jcr/contentloader/internal/DefaultContentCreator.java) 
UPD2: There is a failing's test exception stack trace:

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Node needs to have a name.
at org.apache.sling.jcr.contentloader.internal.DefaultContentCreator.createNode(DefaultContentCreator.java:225)
at org.apache.sling.jcr.contentloader.internal.DefaultContentCreatorTest.createNodeWithoutNameAndTwoInStack(DefaultContentCreatorTest.java:278)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.jmock.integration.junit4.JMock$1.invoke(JMock.java:37)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:107)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

As you can see it throws exception at line 278 which is the line with `contentCreator.createNode(null, null, null);` method call.

Comment: Can you give a complete and reproducible example?

Comment: Just debug this  org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.ExpectedExceptionStatement#evaluate

Comment: Test is failing because code above setting the expected  exception details is throwing an exception. Show us full stacktrace.

Comment: @PetrShypila Wrap `contentCreator.createNode(null, null, null)` within a try-catch block, remove `@Rule` and then confirm that test is passing. Have you debug this code?

Comment: @Ajan yes, I have. And it throws where I expect. I see that all expected configs are configured in `thrown` object (I mean exception and its message). By the way `thrown` object contains two properties `handleAssumptionViolatedExceptions` and `handleAssertionErrors`. Both of them are set to `false`.

Comment: Hm... maybe the `JMock` runner is messing something... Please try to remove `@RunWith(JMock.class)

Comment: @Ajan Finally you were right. With our JMock's runner test passes fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PetrShypila U R welcome ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to summarize discussion from comments: the solution was to remove`JMock` `jUnit` runner.

Comment: You must be using an old version of JMock. Newer versions extend `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` (not `org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner`) and would therefore support rules

Answer (score -1):

Try placing your thrown.expect before the actual call that you expect an exception from

```
@Test
public void createNodeWithoutNameAndTwoInStack() throws RepositoryException {
    thrown.expect(RepositoryException.class); //Doesn't work
    thrown.expectMessage("Node needs to have a name."); //Doesn't work 

    contentCreator.init(U.createImportOptions(true, true, true, false, false),
            new HashMap<String, ContentReader>(), null, null);

    //Making parentNodeStack.size() == 1
    contentCreator.prepareParsing(parentNode, DEFAULT_NAME);

    //Making parentNodeStack.size() == 2
    contentCreator.createNode(uniqueId(), null, null);

    // method should now throw an exception
    contentCreator.createNode(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: It's a wrong idea because now you don't know what line should throw the exception. It would be much better if there would be old-fashioned try-catch ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it doesn't help me. My method still fails with this exception. BTW I also thought that I should call ExpectedException#expect() one line before a method which this exception will throw.

Comment: @Ajan...but wouldn't the last line of the test always be where you'd expect the exception? I can't see any reason to continue with the test if you're expecting an exception from a particular method call. It's probably just a matter of preference but I think using the ExpectedException class is cleaner than using a try-catch. Declaring it at the top gives clear indication of what's expected from the test in my opinion.

Comment: @malificent : It gives clear indication of what's expected but... you are losing information about *where it's expected*.

Comment: @Ajan: where else would the exception to be expected except for the last line of the test? If you expect an exception at a particular point, there is no reason to continue with the test, correct?

Comment: @malificent: I agree but if you expect exception on the last line and exception (from some reason) would be thrown from any of the previous lines then the test would stil pass.

Comment: @Ajan: I don't think that's true. The test will fail with an error...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425995/whats-the-difference-between-failure-and-error-in-junit

Comment: @malificent There are many resources available online about this problem, ex. http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2012/09/26/be-careful-when-using-junit-expected-exceptions/