# Does JUnit5 test result contains "Error", if it does, how to mark a test as "Error"?

Tags: junit5

I'm writing an android JUnit5 test, and have a scenario where I need to mark a `@Test` as **"Error"** instead of **"Failure"**, I'm wondering if that is possible.

I was using `gradle` to run the test, `./gradlew cDAT`.
For instance, the following code is expected to show as **error**, but instead it shows **failure** anyway:

```
@Test
   void test03() {
      throw new ArithmeticException();
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Demo test result as `failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0"`.  
Since there is `errors="0"`, I think it's possible to mark a test as 'Error'.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425995/whats-the-difference-between-failure-and-error-in-junit

Comment: Yeah thanks for your comment, I tried something like this:  


@Test
    void test03() {
        throw new ArithmeticException();
    }


It still shows as a 'failure' instead of an 'error'. I not sure what led to this. 
While in my scenario I need to set the test as 'error'.

Comment: I'm sorry for the formatting, the markdown is a mess in the comment.